# animating a box in android getting a nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So what I'm trying to do is animate a box in android.  In my drawView.java I have

```
    public void box(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1, paint);


    canvas.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2, paint);

    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2, paint);

    canvas.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2, paint);

}
```

In the onCreate method in MainActivity I have the following code.  Where DV is an object that calls on the class DrawView DV;  I receive a NULLPOINTER when I call DV.box(x1,x2, y1, y2).  How do I fix this and why am I getting this error??

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    x1 = display.getWidth()/3;
    y1 = display.getHeight()/3;
    x2 = display.getWidth()-display.getWidth()/3;
    y2 = display.getHeight()- display.getHeight()/3;
    DV.box(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    DV = new DrawView(this);
    preview.addView(DV);
```

The whole point of having the method box is so I can override the previous box so I may draw a completely new one.  Am I doing this wrong? Is there another way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the two lines:

```
DV.box(x1, x2, y1, y2);
DV = new DrawView(this);
```

so that you instantiate `DV` before referencing it.

```
DV = new DrawView(this);
DV.box(x1, x2, y1, y2);
```

Also, it's standard Java convention for variables and fields to start with lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create the DV object before calling that box method:

```
 DV = new DrawView(this);
 DV.box(x1, x2, y1, y2);
```